# Run execute file in Runtime.exec() and get user input

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

How to run c execute file with user input in Java `Runtime().exec()`. Without user 
 input in my c program execute file runs in `Runtime().exec()`:

For example: Below c program if n is predefined and it's execute file runs in
 java runtime()...If n is a user input how to run the execute file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>    
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   setbuf(stdout, NULL); //set buffer null
   int i,n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
       for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
   {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    sleep(1); //delay
   }
} //main
```

Java code ....

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class run3
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 try
 {
 String[] cmd = {"file path"};
 Process p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
 String s;
 BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                                          InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new  
                                          InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
    {    System.out.println(s);    }

          System.out.println("Done.");
   }//try
  catch (IOException ex) 
  { ex.printStackTrace();   }
 } //void
} //main
```

Comment: For God's sake use `ProcessBuilder`!

Comment: Java Native Interface???
http://techforum4u.com/content.php/390-Steps-to-Call-a-C-Program-from-Java

Comment: @Senthil Prabhu. no JNI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve:

- The simplest way to do this would be to pass `n` as a command line argument.
- You could have the C program read `n` from its standard input ... and write to it from the Java side using the `Process` object's `getOutputStream` method.
- You could have the C program open "/dev/console" or "/dev/tty" and read `n` from there.  On Windows I believe you can do this in other ways.

---

OK.  Given that, you just need to call `p.getInputStream()`, write the input to that stream, and close it ... *before* attempting to read the command's output.

Comment: @Stephen..I have c execute file only it get input value from user and print the result.Just I'm trying to execute that c execute file through java.Could you tell little bit more.Thanks